# Passing dynamic attributes between JSP tags?

Tags: java, jsp, attributes, tags

I have a set of JSP tags that use dynamic-attributes to allow for arbitrary HTML attributes to be passed in to them, like this:

```
<%-- tag named a:div --%>
<%@ tag dynamic-attributes="attrs" %>
<div <c:forEach var="attr" items="${attrs}"> ${attr.key}="${attr.value}"</c:foreach>>
</div>
```

I then have another tag that I want to be able to pass dynamic-attributes to & have it just pass them onto the above tag. Something like:

```
<%-- tag using a:div --%>
<%@ tag dynamic-attributes="attrs" %>
<a:div class='big' attrs="${attrs}"/>
```

But *attrs="${attrs}"* doesn't do what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, sadly. The "attrs" object here is a `java.util.Map`, and there's no way to explode that back.

The alternative is to allow your `<a:div>` tag to take a Map attribute which represents those dynamic attributes. Perhaps `<a:div>` could support both dynamic attributes as well as having a Map passed in from somewhere else, and treat them the same using `<c:choose>` or the like?

Comment: Hm, too bad. This is probably what I'll end up doing if I go down this route in the end. I've had some trouble with this & haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: I applied this solution successfully, by supporting both dynamic attributes AND a single `java.util.Map` "dynattrs" attribute. Code becomes `<a:div dynattrs="${attrs}"`